# Reversing characters in a string regardless of the number of spaces - Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, dictionary, join, split

This question is from codewars

Complete the function that accepts a string parameter, and reverses each word in the string. All spaces in the string should be retained.

Here is my code that only works for a string with single spaces, but I can't seem to figure out how to add/subtract anything to it to make it work for a string with more than one space in-between each word.

```
def reverse_words(str)

str.split(" ").map(&:reverse!).join(" ")

end
```

Examples given:

```
('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'), 'ehT kciuq nworb xof spmuj revo eht yzal .god')

('apple'), 'elppa')

('a b c d'), 'a b c d')

('double  spaced  words'), 'elbuod  decaps  sdrow')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest option to tackle this is by using a regex.

```
def reverse_words(str)
  str
    .scan(/(\s*)(\S+)(\s*)/)
    .map { |spacer1, word, spacer2| spacer1 + word.reverse + spacer2 }
    .join
end
```

This searches the string for zero or more whitespaces captured by the first group. Followed by one or more non-whitespaces, captured by the second group. Followed by zero or more whitespaces captured in the third group. Mapping over the resulting array we can combine the spacers back with the reversed word and join the whole thing together.

The above results in the following output:

- ```
  reverse_words('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
  #=> "ehT kciuq nworb xof spmuj revo eht yzal .god"
  ```
- ```
  reverse_words('apple')
  #=> "elppa"
  ```
- ```
  reverse_words('a b c d')
  #=> "a b c d"
  ```
- ```
  reverse_words('double  spaced  words')
  #=> "elbuod  decaps  sdrow"
  ```
- ```
  reverse_words(' foo    bar   ')
  #=> " oof    rab   "
  ```

**References:**

- [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan)
- [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map)
- [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-join)
- [Regular expressions in Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/regexp_rdoc.html)

Comment: Instead of mapping over the array and joining it together. You could also use [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

Comment: Is there another way of adding to the code that I had written? I think the regex /\S+\ might work when inserted into .split? but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You could split on something like `/(?<=\s)(?=\S)/`. `'double  spaced  words'.split(/(?<=\s)(?=\S)/) #=> ["double  ", "spaced  ", "words"]` However you can't simply reverse the elements since the spaces are moved before the word in this case. (The output above is double spaced but not displayed properly by SO.)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
irb(main):023:0> 'double  spaced  words'.split(//).reverse.join
=> "sdrow  decaps  elbuod"
```

Pass regexp so [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) does not omit spaces. There are similar examples in docs

Comment: This does reverse the whole sentence. If I'm reading the question correctly the word position should stay the same while reversing each word.

Answer (score 0):

Just to play with recursion, even if Johan Wentholt answer is the best so far:

```
def part(string)
  if string.count(" ") > 0
    ary = string.partition(/\s{1,}/)
    last = ary.pop
    ary << part(last)
    ary.flatten
  else string
  end
end

part(string).map(&:reverse).join
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
 f = " Hello im the     world"
 ff = f.split #=> ["Hello", "im", "the", "world"]
 ff.each do |a|
       a.reverse! #=> ["olleH", "mi", "eht", "dlrow"]
 end

ff.join! #=> "olleH mi eht dlrow"
```